# Why -pthread working but -lpthread does not?

Tags: hyperlink, g++, pthreads, ld, googletest

I have successfully linked my simple gtest test with command
`g++ -o build/test1 build/test1.o -pthread -lgtest -lgtest_main`

but i'm curios about options -pthread. Why it is not working with -lpthread as 
it working with -lgtest.

And why -gtest doest not working but -pthread without "l" is working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `gcc`, the `-pthread` flag is an indication to the compiler that it should set up things to allow for threaded code. I believe (but I'm not absolutely sure) that *one* of the things it does is add `-lpthread` so that the linker will use the relevant libraries when searching for unresolved symbols.

However, it also does *other* things, like set `-D_REENTRANT` to specify the use of re-entrant code.

In other words, `-lpthread` may not be enough on its own, since it *only* specifies that the threading library should be searched. I tend to use *both* to be certain that it does the right thing - yes, I *am* paranoid :-)

Comment: This is correct in principle, and specifically in its implication that using the `-pthread` option (at both the compilation and link stages) is the right way to build pthreads code with GCC compilers.  To the best of my knowledge, however, `-D_REENTRANT` in particular is not needful for any current GCC compilers, and simply linking with `-lpthread` actually does work.

Answer (score 2):

> I have successfully linked my simple gtest test with command g++ -o
>   build/test1 build/test1.o -pthread -lgtest -lgtest_main
>
> but i'm curios about options -pthread. Why it is not working with
>   -lpthread as it working with -lgtest.

The order of library link options on the command line is significant.  I take it that you tried simply changing `-pthread` to `-lpthread` in place, to get this:

```
g++ -o build/test1 build/test1.o -lpthread -lgtest -lgtest_main
```

But if the gtest or gtest_main library uses any pthreads functions, then `-lpthread` needs to appear later in the library list than those (libraries can be listed more than once if necessary):

```
g++ -o build/test1 build/test1.o -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread
```

Although that's not the appropriate way to build pthreads code with `g++` (as described in your other answer), it typically does work.

> And why -gtest doest not working but -pthread without "l" is
>   working...

`-pthread` is a *specific* compilation option recognized by the GCC suite of compilers.  `-lgtest` is a combination of the *general* `-l` option with `gtest` as an option argument.  One can also write the analogous `-lpthread` option, which, in principle, has a somewhat different meaning than `-pthread`.